# E-books catering to development using the EaselJS library

Tags: javascript, easeljs

Are there any e-books that shows caters to development using the EaselJS library. I searched the internet but could not find any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately no - not at this stage in the game.  I picked it up from web tutorials and by examining code from examples on the web.  Even if you are not making games, this tutorial might be useful:  http://rhuno.com/flashblog/2012/01/07/tutorial-html-5-space-shooter-part-2/

Also, I believe activeTuts web site has a handful of premium pay only easeljs tutorials of high quality.